# Google Places API "request denied" error

Tags: android, google-places-api, google-places

I am trying to call the Google places API in my android app, using the following :
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/xml?query=restaurants+in+Sydney&sensor=true&key=AddYourOwnKeyHere

I have tried using a debug key, and have even tried generating a private key, but all I get is the REQUEST_DENIED response.

I have followed the steps mentioned for generating an Android API key, but still the error.

What am I missing? Is there a definitive guide I can use for using google places api in my android app?

Your suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using Android key for google Place API.
Login on [google console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/) then create a Place API key, try again.
[image]
[image]

Comment: yes, I am using the android key. it doesnt work

Comment: @ufdeveloper Try using Places API like i said. I Tested your query with my own Places API and It works

Comment: ok let me try creating a new project

Comment: @ufdeveloper create a new API project if needed. the First key you got grom API project when turn on Place API is the right one

Comment: it worked. I am using the first key generated, and not the android key. Really appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 3):

1. Delete old api project from api console.
2. Create a new project.
3. Start only the google places api service.
4. Clicked the try it out link
   5 .use the default key it had made.
5. Copied the key from the url field and Use it in app.

Answer (score 1):

In google console, in services tab, have you switched on google maps?
Reference:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#api_key
https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/

Comment: yes, i have activated the service